# Facebook custom tab not visible to non-logged in users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Pretty much what the title says.

There are tons of questions about this but the vast majority was only a matter of a missing HTTPS URL, a couple are due to misconfigured app restrictions, and the rest are unsolved.

I have no country or age restrictions in my app, I have both HTTP and an HTTPS URLs, I can see the page when logged in as a page admin and everything works fine, but when visiting the page while logged out, I don't see the tab.

Also, this is not a matter of clicking the tab and not having any content displayed, like in some other questions here. If I'm logged in with my The actual tab link is missing and if I copy the tab URL from when I'm logged in and then try to access it while logged out, I am simply redirected to the page.

I don't think it matters much but this is a tab that has been created via the Graph API. The Graph API docs don't mention anything about tab visibility, at least as far as I see.

This is driving me crazy, I've been at it for hours and can't find any solution or even a hint at what the problem might be.

Any ideas?

EDIT: All I described above is happening with our staging application, which has a self-signed SSL certificate. The live application, which has a "proper" SSL certificate, works just fine. Could the self-signed certificate be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue this morning. Remove any audience restrictions from your app e.g 13 + or location as this means people have to login to see your app.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I explicitly say that «I have no country or age restrictions in my app». In fact, I have no restrictions at all.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was stupidly simple: it was happening on our staging application but not on our live application because our live application uses a non-test FB app, while staging uses a test FB app, which is never seen by people who are not developers (or other staff) on that app.

Talk about wasted time...